# A theoretical problem in limits .

Tags: limits

My book says that

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=n(a^{n-1}),a>0.$$
Can we apply this to

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^\frac{1}{n}-x^\frac1n}{h}$$

I applied the same thing by dividing numerator and denominator and got the answer.
But I realised on seeing the formula that $a$ in this case is x and $\lim h$ is not tending to $h$ (which is $a$ in the formula) and it is tending to zero instead so can we apply this formula? I am having a theoritical problem. Please help.

Comment: The $-1$ should be in the exponent.

Comment: Please edit it you are right it should be in the exponent

Comment: It is true that the limit is $\frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$. However, from the fact that the limit is $na^{n-1}$ when $n$ is a positive integer, you cannot *deduce* the analogous result for $\frac{1}{n}$. A proof is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.. If $h \to 0$, then $x + h \to x $, so you can apply the formula above

Comment: Please explain in more detail. The term x^1/n is (a) according to me so h should tend to a

Comment: No, x is a, x+h is x, while n is 1/n

Comment: Ok thanks got it